# String to Unknown number type in Java

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to make a generic binary search tree class that reads numbers from a file and builds a BST. I got all the separate numbers into an array, but I am stuck on how to convert them to an unspecified type.

```
class ModifiedBinarySearchTree <N extends Number & Comprable<N>>{
    private BinaryNode<N> root;

    public void treeInput(String fileName) throws Exception{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new FileReader(fileName));
    String[] nums = br.readLine().split("\\s");
    for(String num : nums){
         //do something to cast number as type n
         //I tried:
         N number = N.valueOf(num);
         insert(number);
         //but that gave me a compile error
    }
```

Is there a way to make this work? I tried just converting the string to a double, but then I had no way to get from double to n.

Comment: Welcome to SO. It would help if you showed how you are instantiating this class and calling this method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All [`Number`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html) classes have a `String` constructor, so you can safely use reflection to invoke that constructor. Due to [runtime type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), the type `N` is not accessible in your method, so you must pass a concrete *class token* to the constructor to get a reference to the constructor for the class of the type:

```
class ModifiedBinarySearchTree <N extends Number & Comparable<N>>{
    private BinaryNode<N> root;
    private final Constructor<N> constructor;

    // pass in a Number class, eg new ModifiedBinarySearchTree(Integer.class)
    public ModifiedBinarySearchTree(Class<N> clazz) {
        try {
            constructor = clazz.getConstructor(String.class);
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public void treeInput(String fileName) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            for (String num : line.split("\\s")) {
                insert(constructor.newInstance(num));
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could pass the class object in with the method instead of the constructor, but that would somewhat defeat the "genericness" of your class.

I also removed spelling mistakes, abbreviated some code and added a `while` loop that seemed to be missing.

Comment: I'd highlight the issue with erasure more; missing the fact that type parameter values don't exist at runtime seems to be a common mistake.

Comment: A couple questions, class.getConstructor(type) will return whatever constructor matches that parameter list? constructor.newInstance(s) should be constructor.newInstance(num) right? and i get a compile error Constructor<N> symbol not found, is there a library I need to include?

Comment: @user146515 oops! yes `s` --> `num` (a copy-paste error!). Yes: `MyClass.class.getConstructor(String)` gives you the constructor with one String parameter, which when invoked is like calling `new MyClass("foo")`. You need to `import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;`